# How to use custom file system jar for hive in EMR

Tags: hadoop, hive, filesystems, amazon-emr

I want to use a custom file system lets name it X, for my hive Application in EMR which is different from existing file systems example EMRFS, HDFS. But when I switch to my hive shell and try

```
add jar s3://sample/X.jar;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST(sample_key1 int, sample_key2 STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 'X://sample/test/path';
```

It throws an error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException No FileSystem for scheme X.
```

Usually I do this to get it to work in spark:
1. spark-shell --jars s3://sample/X.jar
2. spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.x.impl", "{My FS jar main file.}")
3. spark.read.csv("X://sample/test/path").

Maybe what I am missing is the 2nd step(conf setting), but I tried the same thing in hive shell as:

```
SET fs.x.impl=<My FS jar main file.>
```

** Update:
I tried giving the second step as a part of hive-site configuration, now it seems it understands that an X file system exists, but gives the following error instead('ClassNotFoundException') even though the same thing worked for emrfs with spark, maybe there is a different way for hive to parse this jar.:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ckp.fs.CkpFS not found)
```

But that too didn't work any idea what I can do here?

Comment: Can you add the jar in hive auxlib path(`/usr/lib/hive/auxlib`). And the following properties in hive-site.xml `hive.aux.jars.path=/usr/lib/hive/auxlib`. Finally restart the hive-server

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Hey same exception :( ClassNotFound.

Comment: In hadoop `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml` can you add `fs.x.impl=<My FS jar main file.>` this. And also drop the same jar to `/usr/lib/hadoop/`. Finally restart hadoop.

Comment: Also remove these properties from hive-site.xml. after restarting hadoop can you do `hdfs dfs -ls X://sample/test/path` this should work.